# sql query for summary value between tables

Tags: sql

Say you have two tables

**Department**

dept_id

dept_name

dept_sub_id

**SubDepartment**

dept_sub_id

sub_dept_name

sub_dept_total_employees

how would i write a query which would give the **dept_name** from **Department** for the department which has the most total employees from the associated **Subdepartment** table, the total **sub_dept_total_employees**, where there is a relationship between **dept_sub_id**

I want the **dept_name** from **Department**, not the total **sub_dept_total_employees** count

Thanks

Comment: Hello Petewifi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question would find an answer more easily if you could provide sample data from both tables, along with your expected results (a few rows of data is usually enough). You are also supposed to show your current attempt at solving this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle**

```
SELECT dept_name
FROM department a
JOIN
  (SELECT dept_sub_id
   FROM subdepartment
   ORDER BY sub_dept_total_employees DESC) b ON a.dept_sub_id = b.dept_sub_id
WHERE b.rownum = 1
```

**Other DBs(check documentation to see if `row_number()` is supported)**

```
SELECT dept_name
FROM department a
JOIN
  (SELECT dept_sub_id,
          row_number() over(
                     ORDER BY sub_dept_total_employees DESC) AS rn
   FROM subdepartment) b ON a.dept_sub_id = b.dept_sub_id
WHERE b.rn = 1
```

Comment: MS SQL Server has row_number but that wouldn't work with that syntax. Rather would be Row_Number() over (Order by ...). However, not all versions have that function.

Comment: @CetinBasoz That's a really good catch. Thanks! Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
select d.dept_name
from Department as d
inner join SubDepartment as s on s.dept_sub_id = d.dept_sub_id
where s.sub_dept_employees =
(select max(sub_dept_employees)
from SubDepartment);
```

There might be more than one department.